# Empty variables while attempting to scrape a table from a webpage using rvest

Tags: html, r, web-scraping, rvest

I am brand new to coding in r and am trying to scrape the following table into a data frame:

https://www.zyxware.com/articles/5363/list-of-fortune-500-companies-and-their-websites-2015

It should be fairly straightforward, but my variables have 0 observations and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. The code I used is:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

#set the url of the website
url <- read_html("https://www.zyxware.com/articles/5363/list-of-fortune-500-companies-and-their-websites-2015")

#Scrape variables
rank <- url %>% html_nodes(".td:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
company <- url %>% html_nodes(".td:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text()
website <- url %>% html_nodes(".td~ td+ td") %>% html_text()

#Create dataframe
fortune500 <- data.frame(company,rank,website)
```

Was attempting to follow this [walkthrough](https://data-science-blog.com/blog/2020/11/18/web-scraping-using-r/). Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by calling `html_table()` on `url` and picking the first element.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("https://www.zyxware.com/articles/5363/list-of-fortune-500-companies-and-their-websites-2015")
url %>% html_table() %>% pluck(1)
#> # A tibble: 500 × 3
#>     Rank Company            Website                  
#>    <int> <chr>              <chr>                    
#>  1     1 Walmart            www.walmart.com          
#>  2     2 Exxon Mobil        www.exxonmobil.com       
#>  3     3 Chevron            www.chevron.com          
#>  4     4 Berkshire Hathaway www.berkshirehathaway.com
#>  5     5 Apple              www.apple.com            
#>  6     6 General Motors     www.gm.com               
#>  7     7 Phillips 66        www.phillips66.com       
#>  8     8 General Electric   www.ge.com               
#>  9     9 Ford Motor         www.ford.com             
#> 10    10 CVS Health         www.cvshealth.com        
#> # … with 490 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Alternatively, your original code will also work, you just need to remove the period from in front of `td`.  The `.` identifies an object class, so you were trying to identify object of class `td`.  Without the `.` in front, it will look for tags called `td`, which is what you want.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
url <- read_html("https://www.zyxware.com/articles/5363/list-of-fortune-500-companies-and-their-websites-2015")
rank <- url %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(1)") %>% html_text()
company <- url %>% html_nodes("td:nth-child(2)") %>% html_text()
website <- url %>% html_nodes("td~ td+ td") %>% html_text()
fortune500 <- data.frame(company,rank,website)
head(fortune500)
#>              company rank                   website
#> 1            Walmart    1           www.walmart.com
#> 2        Exxon Mobil    2        www.exxonmobil.com
#> 3            Chevron    3           www.chevron.com
#> 4 Berkshire Hathaway    4 www.berkshirehathaway.com
#> 5              Apple    5             www.apple.com
#> 6     General Motors    6                www.gm.com
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-01 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>